# How to clean up string to load to an array in Python split?

Tags: python

I have a dynamically created string set separated with `;` now I want to convert them to an array like

```
st = "app; map; 'better tap'; nima;"

st_n = st.split(';')
print(st_n)
```

This is working fine **until** there is only one word like `app` but when there is a `'better tap'` (which I am getting a lot of them) it is wrapping them in an extra `""`. How can I fix this?

> ['app', ' map', " 'better tap'", ' nima']

Comment: What is the expected output? If you simply want to remove the quotation marks, use `[word.strip("' ") for word in st.split(';')]`

Comment: From the start of your question, it sounds like it's your own code causing this issue prior to what you've shown?

Comment: What should happen for `st = "app; 'better; tap'; nima"`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could remove the ' from better tap before splitting:

```
st = "app; map; 'better tap'; nima;"

st_n = st.replace('\'', '').split(';')
print(st_n)
```

Gives:

> ['app', ' map', ' better tap', ' nima', '']

Comment: Presuming there's no valid `'` characters in words that should be preserved. e.g. the word `don't`

Comment: @HåkenLid: Good point. You could add your solution from the comments as an answer, too, which takes care of this issue as far as I can see.

Comment: i would replace print(st_n) with print(st_n[:-1]) to ignore the last empty value that comes from splitting.

Comment: @HarshaJasti  That assumes there is a final ;. Wasn't sure every input would have that.  I think it would be better to remove empty strings after.

Comment: @ChristianSloper you're correct. i was being specific to the question asked. but, you're right.

Answer (score 3):

one clean way is to use `csv` module:

```
st = "app; map; 'better tap'; nima;"

import csv

tokens = next(csv.reader([st],delimiter=";",quotechar="'",skipinitialspace=True))
```

result:

```
['app', 'map', 'better tap', 'nima', '']
```

(you could filter the empty field in the end, or preprocess the string with `st.strip(";")` if it's a problem).

the strong point is that it's robust to delimiter chars if enclosed in quotes. Change `st` like:

```
st = "app; map; 'better ; tap'; nima"
```

you'll get

```
['app', 'map', 'better ; tap', 'nima']
```

This string can be parsed by `csv` module properly thanks to the obscure `skipinitialspace` parameter which tolerates (and strips) the space after the delimiter.